# What is the best strategy to obtain the field name from a class using a functional interface getter method

Tags: java, reflection

I need to obtain the field name of a POJO class using a `@FunctionalInterface` that models the `[get/is]XXXX` methods.

I'm already using the [cronn reflection-util](https://github.com/cronn-de/reflection-util) library to do some work, and for now, I can obtain the field name when it follows the POJO specification (where the field name respect the `[get/is]XXXX` format).

For example, given the following class:

```java
public class MyBean {
    private String testName;
    public String getTestName() { return testName; }
    public void setTestName(String testName) { this.testName = testName; }
}
```

I can obtain the field name using the following source code:

```java
String fieldName = de.cronn.reflection.util.PropertyUtils(MyBean.java, MyBean::getName).getName();
```

Besides that it is working for me, I would like to know if there is some better strategy or other way that performs better?

Comment: Why? If it works, and if it's only in a test system, why do you care? Get on with the testing.

Comment: For now it is in testing stage. But in future the software will be used intensively in production.

Comment: I have to ask. Why the complication with the lambdas? You already have to know the name of the method to provide the lambda. If you know the method name, it's already easy to determine the field name. Wrapping a method into a lambda just forces you to do strange runtime proxy acrobatics (that this library does under the hood) to extract the name again. Both slower and harder.

Comment: I agree with your performance concerns. However, the use of lambda makes easy for IDE applies refactoring of source code when changing the method name.

Comment: I have thinking deeply about this problem. My final assumption is to use publim static and final variables to describe the field names on classes. By this way, I can use the capabilities from IDE's to apply refactorings and it will be easy for "users" access the field names.